# How to transfer data via reactor's subscriber context?

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I'm a new for a project reactor, but i have task to send some information from classic spring rest controller to some service, which is interacts with different system. Whole project developed with project reactor.
Here is my rest controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

@Autowired
Service service;

@PostMapping("/path")
public Mono<String> test(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) throws Exception {
    testService.saveHeader(headers.get("header"));
    return service.getData();
}
```

And here is my service:

```
@Service
public class Service {

private Mono<String> monoHeader;
private InteractionService interactor;

public Mono<String> getData() {
    return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> interactor.interact(monoHeader.block()));

}

public void saveHeader(String header) {
    String key = "header";
    monoHeader = Mono.just("")
            .flatMap( s -> Mono.subscriberContext()
                    .map( ctx -> s + ctx.get(key)))
            .subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put(key, header));
}
```

Is it acceptable solution?

Comment: `testService.saveHeader(..)` looks like a typo. It is probably `service.saveHeader()`.

Answer (score 1):

Fisrt off, I don't think you need the `Context` here. It is useful to implicitly pass data to a `Flux` or a `Mono` that you don't create (eg. one that a database driver creates for you). But here you're in charge of creating the `Mono<String>`.

Does the service `saveHeader` really achieve something? The call seem transient in nature: you always immediately call the `interactor` with the last saved header. (there could be a side effect there where two parallel calls to your endpoint end up overwriting each other's headers).

If you really want to store the headers, you could add a list or map in your service, but the most logical path would be to add the header as a parameter of `getData()`.

This eliminates `monoHeader` field and `saveHeader` method.

Then `getData` itself: you don't need to ever `block()` on a `Mono` if you aim at returning a `Mono`. Adding an input parameter would allow you to rewrite the method as:

```
public Mono<String> getData(String header) {
    return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> interactor.interact(header));
}
```

Last but not least, blocking.
The `interactor` seems to be an external service or library that is not reactive in nature. If the operation involves some latency (which it probably does) or blocks for more than a few milliseconds, then it should run on a separate thread.

`Mono.fromSupplier` runs in whatever thread is *subscribing* to it. In this case, Spring WebFlux will subscribe to it, and it will run in the Netty eventloop thread. If you block that thread, it means no other request can be serviced in the whole application!

So you want to execute the `interactor` in a dedicated thread, which you can do by using `subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`.

All in all:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    Service service;

    @PostMapping("/path")
    public Mono<String> test(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) throws Exception {
        return service.getData(headers.get("header"));
    }
}

@Service
public class Service {

    private InteractionService interactor;

    public Mono<String> getData(String header) {
        return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> interactor.interact(header))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that you meant to use 'Mono.defer()' instead of 'Mono.fromSupplier()' in your implementation of `getData()`.

Comment: nope. if interactor is imperative, there's no particular need for defer. the supplier is already making the call lazy

Comment: ACK. I see you are right. The supplier is called at subscription time.

Answer (score 0):

> How to transfer data via reactor's subscriber context?

> Is it acceptable solution?

No.

Your code of `saveHeader()` method is an equivalent of simple

```
public void saveHeader(String header) {
    monoHeader = Mono.just(header);
}
```

A `subscriberContext` is needed if you consume the value elsewhere - if the mono is constructed elsewhere. In your case (where you have all code before your eyes in the same method) just use the actual value.

---

BTW, there are many ways to implement your `getData()` method.

One is as suggested by Simon Baslé to get rid of a separate `saveHeader()` method.

One other way, if you have to keep your `monoHeader` field, could be

```
public Mono<String> getData() {
    return monoHeader.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .map(header -> interactor.interact(header));
}
```